# NPE with retrofit and nested JSON response

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am using retrofit 1.9 and I'm having some trouble getting the values from nested JSON response. Here is the response

```
{
  "access_token": "83ebeabdec09f6670863766f792ead24d61fe3f9",
  "athlete": {
    "id": 227615,
    "resource_state": 3,
    ...
  }
}
```

I have a class to handle the response:

```
public class AuthResponse {

    String accessToken;
    StravaAthlete stravaAthlete;

    public AuthResponse(String accessToken, StravaAthlete stravaAthlete) {
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
        this.stravaAthlete = stravaAthlete;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }

    public StravaAthlete getStravaAthlete() {
        return stravaAthlete;
    }
}
```

and a class for the nested JSON object:

```
public class StravaAthlete {

    String id;

    public StravaAthlete(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately whenever I call `authResponse.getStravaAthlete().getId()` I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.drdp.rideart.api.model.StravaAthlete.getId()' on a null object reference
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have retrofit logging set to full and can verify the information is in the response in the format I expect

Comment: is retrofit set up correctly ?

Comment: I presume so. Its working for everything else I need it for. This is the first time I am trying to access anything nested though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`accessToken` and `StravaAthlete` are not key of your JSON. That's why you are getting null. You can either change them into `access_token` and  `athlete`, or use the `@SerializedName` annotation. E.g.

```
public class AuthResponse {

   @SerializedName("access_token")
   String accessToken;
   @SerializedName("athlete")
   StravaAthlete stravaAthlete;
```

Comment: Doh. Thanks for spotting this

Answer (score 1):

the first this i can see here is the name of the field `athlete` should match the field in your class `stravaAthlete` or add annotation     `@SerializedName(value="athlete")`